# Continuous probability distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

I dont understand how for a continuous probability distribution f(x) that the probability of getting one individual x is 0. Surely if you put a value into your formula this gives the value of the probability of that one value ?

Comment: That function is a density, not a probability.  It can, for example, be greater than $1$.  To get a probability out of it, you need to integrate over a region.

Comment: Notice the sentence in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Further_details): "If a probability distribution admits a density, then the probability of every one-point set {a} is zero; the same holds for finite and countable sets."